# Ruby regex include all alphabets, numbers and /

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

I know this might be asked time and again. But I'm really stuck with this. I've got it to work for including numbers and alphabets but I have no idea on how to include "/" also.

This is what I have,

```
 name.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
```

So if name is `"Cool Stuff *(#/"` it returns `"CoolStuff"`. I'd just *like* it to return `"CoolStuff/"`.

Comment: Hi @Swathi. You may try this `name.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z\/]/, '')`. ie, just add the pattern which matches the forward slash inside  negated character class.

Comment: Great thanks! If you'd like, post this as an answer so that I can mark it correct.

Comment: Cool. Was trying to help you out.

Comment: Another option is to use the `%r{...}` literal. It allows you to use `/` within the regular expression, i.e. `%r{[^0-9A-Za-z/]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The / is a special character that must be 'escaped' (meaning to take the / literally, and not for a switch or special meaning). So you have:

```
 name.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
```

But also realize you could shorten your RegEx statement by making it case insensitive by adding an 'i' after the ending slash and therefore allowing you to drop either the [A-Z] or the [a-z] part. So you could have instead:

```
name.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Z\/]/i, '')
```

Hope this helps!